# Implementing math operations in Qualtrics- SOS

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm new to Qualtrics/JavaScript... would appreciate help on

```
Var block1= [parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/1}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/2}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/3}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/4}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/5}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/6}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/7}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/8}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/9}"), parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/10}")];

`for(i=0;i<block1.length;i++) {
`diff_array[i]= block1[i+1]- block1[i]}`
```

Next, I want to do the following: 
-find ones in array
    `num_switch_block1= number of ones in difference array)`

-create lambda variable- 
    `lambda_multiplier= [.7, .9, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3]`

Is there a more elegant way to increment that array? Should I set this as embedded data? -multiply difference array by lambda_multiplier

```
`var mult = multiply(diff_array,lambda_multiplier);`
```

-then reduce this array to only the non-zero values
    `mult.filter (Boolean)`

Am I using the right functions/doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you will do with the array mult, but here is code to create it (untested):

```
    var block1= [parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/1}"),
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/2}"),
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/3}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/4}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/5}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/6}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/7}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/8}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/9}"), 
      parseInt("${q://QID664/SelectedAnswerRecode/10}")];
    var lambda_multiplier = [.7, .9, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3];
    var mult = [];
    for(i=0;i<lambda_multiplier.length;i++) {
     mult[i] = (block1[i+1] - block1[i]) * lambda_multiplier[i];
    }
    mult = mult.filter(Number); //remove 0s from mult
```

Comment: I like your for loop- more efficient:) can I set mult.filter(Number); to a variable?